# how can i use wildcard * in curl command to download build file in zip format from artifactory sevrer.?

Tags: jenkins, curl, wget, artifactory

I am trying to download a zip build file from artifactory server from a recursive dynamic folder something like

```sh
curl -u username:password -O "http://artifactory_url:8040/artifactory/Target_file_path/Releases/000.00.05_*/Target_file*.zip"
```

Note: am calling this command from Jenkins

recursive direcory:000_00_05_BuildDate/Target_file_000_0005_BuildfileDate.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the Jenkins Artifactory plugin or the JFrog CLI:

**Jenkins Artifactory plugin:**

```
def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'artifactory-url', username: 'username', password: 'password'
def downloadSpec = """{
 "files": [
  {
      "pattern": "bazinga-repo/*.zip",
      "target": "bazinga/"
    }
 ]
}"""
server.download spec: downloadSpec
```

Read more about the download command in the Jenkins Artifactory plugin [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-UploadingandDownloadingFiles).

**JFrog CLI**:

```
// Download JFrog CLI
curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh -s v2

// Download artifacts:
./jfrog rt dl repo/path/* --url=<artifactory-url> --user=<username> --password=<password>
```

Read more about the download command in the JFrog CLI [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles).

Comment: Thanks Yahavi for your quick response.
I have to achieve this with curl command from jenkins .